# Configure Apache Hive for LLAP without using slider

Tags: apache, hive, apache-hive, tez

There's a new feature in hive called LLAP. During the investigation I've found out that it's quite difficult to configure LLAP so there's a component called Apache Slider that will configure it. Still I couldn't find any documentation for manual configuration without Slider. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LLAP

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this documentation.

https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/interactive-sql-hadoop-hive-llap/

[Updated] it seems like the above page was removed by Hortonworks
The only option I can suggested now is

https://www.google.com/search?q=hadoop+interactive+sql+hadoop+hive+llap&oq=hadoop+interactive+sql+hadoop+hive+llap&gs_l=serp.3..35i39k1.5338.10878.0.11135.4.4.0.0.0.0.199.655.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.3.499.N2KWHY3UFi8

Comment: It's a dead link

Comment: @chhantyal well looks like hortonworks removed it. Doing a google search will give this as the first link https://www.google.com/search?q=hadoop+interactive-sql-hadoop-hive-llap&oq=hadoop+interactive-sql-hadoop-hive-llap&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.1982j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8